# How can I remove references to System.Deployment in mono solution for Linux?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono

I am trying to compile the great open-source dotNET 4.5 program, "Ketarin" with MonoDevelop on Lubuntu 16.04.1.
There is an error:
    `/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets: Warning: Reference 'System.Deployment' not resolved (Ketarin)`

From what I have read, *System.Deployment* is needed for one-click installation. This application doesn't need that, so what I want to do is remove the reference that makes the compiler want to find *System.Deployment*.

I have searched all the code for *System.Deployment* without finding it. I have also searched the code for some classes that are referred to in web pages to do with *System.Deployment* without finding anything.

The code is at
https://bitbucket.org/jimh44/ketarin4linux

Can someone help?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at .csproj file and edit it with text editor (remove "Reference" xml element)

this line - https://bitbucket.org/jimh44/ketarin4linux/src/a9b077be682ae7dce7c76c0df039fd7ae333f020/Ketarin.csproj?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#Ketarin.csproj-93

You can also do the same through IDE (how to remove reference:
VisualStudio - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx
MonoDevelop - http://www.monodevelop.com/documentation/solutions-and-projects-explained/#adding-references-to-other-projects)